# Wrong count(*) in pl/sql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle 11g Express Edition 11.2.0

Table "RIGHT" data (contains only 1 row with name = Test):

Id | Name

1   Test

2   New2

3   New14

...

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RIGHT WHERE name = 'Test';

**Result = 1**

I have procedure in package TEST:

```
    create or replace
    PACKAGE BODY TEST
    AS
    PROCEDURE FIND_RIGHT(rightName IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
      countrows       NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countrows FROM RIGHT WHERE name = rightName;

    /* DEBUG POINT !!! in this point countrows = 212 !!!! */
    ...
    END;
    END TEST;
```

And run it from other procedure:

```
    DECLARE
      rightName VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
      rightName := 'Test';
      TEST.FIND_RIGHT(rightName);
    END;
```

I run debugger (in Oracle SQL Developer) and debug point after select. 
I see countrows = 212.

**Why countrows != 1 ???**

**UPDATED:**
All transaction is commited. Open only 1 session (from SQL Developer). Table Rights has 3 indexes (table is big, I don't write all colums in the post). Procedures have many input params (custom objects), but I drop extra information.

**UPDATED #2:**
I change code to

```
    create or replace
    PACKAGE BODY TEST
    AS
    PROCEDURE FIND_RIGHT(rightName IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
      countrows       NUMBER;
      testVar       VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
      testVar := 'Test';
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countrows FROM RIGHT WHERE name = testVar;

    /* in this point countrows = 1  */
    ...
    END;
    END TEST;
```

Comment: did you run the count(*) and the proc call in the same sql developer window? Also do you have any uncommitted transactions (as the window that ran the pl/sql call may have inserted rows but not committed them). best to test both in the same session via sql*plus and show the output.

Comment: Yes. I call proc in sql developer window. All transactions is commited. Open only 1 session.

Comment: and if you try the same from a single SQL*plus session instead? can you show the output of that from the sql*plus prompt please?

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple tables named 'RIGHT' in the same database but in different schemas?  You may want to try fully qualifying the tables being accessed, i.e. use SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME.

Comment: No. I login as user_shema_name with access to only one shema.

Comment: May be it Oracle 11g XE bug? I'm going to install new patches tommorow and repeat run this case.

Comment: I believe that RIGHT is a reserved word - can you change the name of the table (or create another one for test purposes) and try it with the new table name?

Comment: My table name it's CORE_RIGHT (I changed name for post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your table contains a column called "rightName"?

if this is the case your orginal query would compare the "name" and "rightName" columns instead of using the procedure argument.

Try changing the argument name.